# How to fix crash on launch in Android Studio 4?

Tags: java, android

It happened when after I installed some intellij related plugins after importing a native opencv project https://github.com/leadrien/opencv_native_androidstudio/blob/master/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.
On startup it throws in this error.

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.a.a.b.a.p.a(p.java:182)
    at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:348)
    at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:172)
    at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$startApp$5(StartupUtil.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.EdtInvocationManager.executeWithCustomManager(EdtInvocationManager.java:73)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:243)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:214)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:45)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.ui.scale.JBUIScale.lambda$static$0(JBUIScale.java:72)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.AtomicNotNullLazyValue$1.compute(AtomicNotNullLazyValue.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.AtomicNotNullLazyValue.getValue(AtomicNotNullLazyValue.java:37)
    at com.intellij.ui.scale.JBUIScale.lambda$static$1(JBUIScale.java:152)
    at com.intellij.util.LazyInitializer$MutableNotNullValue.initialize(LazyInitializer.java:113)
    at com.intellij.util.LazyInitializer$NullableValue.get(LazyInitializer.java:41)
    at com.intellij.util.LazyInitializer$MutableNotNullValue.get(LazyInitializer.java:102)
    at com.intellij.ui.scale.JBUIScale.lambda$static$2(JBUIScale.java:170)
    at com.intellij.util.LazyInitializer$MutableNotNullValue.initialize(LazyInitializer.java:113)
    at com.intellij.util.LazyInitializer$NullableValue.get(LazyInitializer.java:41)
    at com.intellij.util.LazyInitializer$MutableNotNullValue.get(LazyInitializer.java:102)
    at com.intellij.ui.scale.JBUIScale.scale(JBUIScale.java:294)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.JBInsets.create(JBInsets.java:41)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:457)
    ... 11 more

-----
JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
/opt/android-studio/jre/jre
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by delete three plugins under `~/.AndroidStudio4.0/config/plugins`

```
idea-multimarkdown
markdown
Gauge-Java-Intellij
```

Comment: It's a plugin issue. With Android 4.1.1 the plugins are under `~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`

Comment: `rm -r ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/idea-multimarkdown/` did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by deleting the latest plugins in  `~/.AndroidStudio4.0/config/plugins/` Gauge-Java-Intellij and Markdown were causing issues in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, had problems with the markdown plugin.

I solved keeping the latest plugin in *~/.AndroidStudio4.0/config/plugins/* and removing the old version in *.../android-studio-4.0.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/markdown-0.1.25.jar*.